# Jest unit test with Luxon: how do I mock .setZone('local')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, luxon

I have a very simple date component:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
export const SimpleDateCell = ({ item, itemKey }) => {
    const isoDateString = item[itemKey];

    if (!isoDateString) {
        return null;
    }

    const formattedDate = DateTime
        .fromISO(isoDateString, { zone: 'utc' })
        .setZone('local')
        .toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_MED);

    return (
        <time dateTime={isoDateString} title={isoDateString}>
            {formattedDate}
        </time>
    ); };
```

And I was testing it locally with simply:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import SimpleDateCell from './SimpleDateCell'; 
import { DateTime, Settings } from 'luxon';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const testData = {
    companyName: 'test company',
    tenantId: 'ai/prod/00DA0000000XoMwMAK',
    // this will be different on different servers when .setZone('local')
    createdDate: '2019-02-13T15:53:00', };

describe('SimpleDateCell', () => {
    it('should match the snapshot', () => {


        const tree = renderer
            .create(
                <SimpleDateCell item={testData} itemKey="createdDate" />
            ).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });  });
```

The problem is the unit test has to be run in the same timezone as I make the snapshot.  So our CI server is rejecting this.

**Is there a way to make this pass in any timezone?**  Maybe mock the  setZone('local') response?  Any CI experts out there use luxon?

Thank you!

Comment: did you try [`Settings.defaultZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/settings.js~Settings.html#static-set-defaultZoneName) ?

Comment: THAT DID IT!! Thank you!  And you made me look very wise among my team.

I encourage you to put it in as an official response.  I want to get credit from others!

Comment: here official answer goes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Settings.defaultZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/settings.js~Settings.html#static-set-defaultZoneName) should work. Just in case I highlight: it affects all methods say `DateTime.local()`. Somebody was [already confused](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/333) by that.

As an alternative you may mock native `Date` with [`timezone-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-mock) or [`timezoned-date`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezoned-date) that I believe should also help. And that approach would be more consistent if for any reason some part of your code works with native `Date` rather luxon's `DateTime`.

Comment: Oh I spent hours trying to mock DateTime.  For some reason the examples for mocking a chained module hadnt worked for me yet so I was thrilled to get your Settings suggestion.

For others, this was my test after  @skyboyer responded:

Comment: describe('SimpleDateCell', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        // So that local will not be used in tests
        Settings.defaultZoneName = 'utc';
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        // To return the option of local
        Settings.defaultZoneName = 'local';
    });

    it('should match the snapshot', () => {

        const tree = renderer
            .create(
                <SimpleDateCell item={testData} itemKey="createdDate" />
            ).toJSON();

        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});